# how to make radio button checked on condition based?

Tags: angular, radio-button

I want to make radio button checked on condition based. Like when `index=>4`, button 4 should be checked. My HTML code is like that:

```
<input id="rating5" type="radio" name="rating" value="5">
<label for="rating5">5</label>
<input id="rating4" type="radio" name="rating" value="4">
<label for="rating4">4</label>
<input id="rating3" type="radio" name="rating" value="3">
<label for="rating3">3</label>
<input id="rating2" type="radio" name="rating" value="2" >
<label for="rating2">2</label>
<input id="rating1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1">
<label for="rating1">1</label>
```

Comment: Where is the value of index defined?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing where `index` comes from, but assuming it's serverside, you could put a PHP if statement right inside the input tag like this.

```
 <input id="rating4" <?php if ($index >=4){echo 'checked="checked"';} ?>
 type="radio" name="rating" value="4">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this working in a project of mine. Trick is to bind the checked property to a boolean expression.

**HTML**

```
<input id="rating4" type="radio" name="Rating" [checked]="index == 4" (click)="index = 4">
<label for="rating4">4</lable>
```

**JS**

```
@Component({
   .
   .
   .
 })
export class MyClass {
  index: number;

  constructor() {
     this.index = 4; 
  }

}
```

Basically the radio button will be checked if index equals the matched value, and clicking that radio button updates it in the component. With this example as well we default the selected button to 4, but you could default it to -1 if you wanted nothing selected.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working fine for me. The address is being provided from map function -

```
<input
     id="address-radio-button"
     value={address.address}
     name="platform"
     type="radio"
     checked={address.isDefault ? true : false}
     onChange={() => changeShippingAddress(address, index)}
/>
```